# jquery cakephp: post method alerts the correct result string locally but not working on remote server

Tags: jquery, cakephp, remote-server

The following jquery and cakephp code works perfect on my localhost alerting the correct result_str but it doesn't work on the remote server. I have included the outputs at the end for both localhost and remote server.

The post method is working, but not displaying the correct output remotely.

I've already verified that the email id i'm entering is exisiting on the remote db.

The debug($merryparent_info) in merry_parent model is not displaying at all both locally and remotely.

Please take a look at [link to my site](http://www.merryflowers.com/students/add)

When the user enters the parent information email id and presses the tab button, 2 alert boxes pops up. The first one displays the email_id passed in the post method and the second alert displays the result_str.

Can someone tell me on where i'm going wrong. I've been trying to solve this for the last 4 days. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#MerryParentEmail").change(function(){
            //txt=$("#MerryParentEmail").val();
            email_id=$("#MerryParentEmail").serialize();
            $.post("/students/get_parent_info",email_id,function(result_str){
                                 alert("result_str: "+result_str);
            });
          });
  </script>
```

students_controller.php

```
function get_parent_info(){
//$this->layout=false;
 if (!empty($this->data)){

    $merryparent_info=$this->Student->MerryParent->getMerryParents($this->data['MerryParent']['email']);
    print_r($merryparent_info);
    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['initial'].'*****';
    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['name'].'*****';
    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['landline'].'*****';
    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['mobile'].'*****';
    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['address'].'*****';
    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['state_id'].'*****';
    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['city_id'].'*****';
    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['postal_code'].'*****';
    }
}
```

merry_parent.php model

```
function getMerryParents($field_value){
    if (is_int($field_value))
        $conditions=array('merryParent.id'=>$field_value);
    else
        $conditions=array('merryParent.email'=>$field_value);

    //debug($conditions);

    $merryparent_info=$this->find('first',array(
                                'conditions'=>$conditions,
                                'recursive'=>-1   //fetches merry_parents table data only not the associated data
                                ));
          debug($merryparent_info);
    return $merryparent_info;
}
```

localhost output:

first alert

```
 email_id: data%5BMerryParent%5D%5Bemail%5D=banana8%40gmail.com
```

second alert

```
 result_str: Array
  (
    [MerryParent] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38
            [initial] => Ms
            [name] => banana kaur
            [username] => banana8
            [email] => banana8@gmail.com
            [password] => 7b311dc3e6d4862caf024b65410c793adfc530bc
            [landline] => 
            [mobile] => 8487234783
            [address] => 99 fruits road
            [state_id] => 14
            [city_id] => 81
            [postal_code] => 877979
            [created] => 2012-02-08 05:24:49
            [modified] => 2012-02-15 15:46:05
        )
  )
  Ms*****banana kaur**********8487234783*****99 fruits road*****14*****81*****877979*****
```

remote server output:

first alert

```
 email_id: data%5BMerryParent%5D%5Bemail%5D=banana8%40gmail.com
```

second alert

```
result_str: ****************************************
```

Comment: Could you post a debug of `$this->data['MerryParent']['email']` in the `get_parent_info()` function? And could you provide a debug of `$this->Student->MerryParent->getMerryParents($this->data['MerryParent']['email']);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was with the code MerryParent Model. There was nothing wrong in my jquery code.

In MerryParent model,

```
function getMerryParents($field_value){         
if (is_int($field_value))         
    $conditions=array('merryParent.id'=>$field_value);         
else         
    $conditions=array('merryParent.email'=>$field_value);         

//debug($conditions);         

$merryparent_info=$this->find('first',array(         
                            'conditions'=>$conditions,         
                            'recursive'=>-1   //fetches merry_parents table data only not the associated data         
                            ));         
      debug($merryparent_info);         
return $merryparent_info;         
}
```

I changed merryParent.id to MerryParent.id and  merryParent.email to MerryParent.email and it works now on the remote server.